# Log function with negative observations

Tags: stata

I have the following data and I would like to apply the `log()` function:

```
 v1 
 2 
 3 
 4 
-1 
 5
```

Expected output:

```
 v1
 2  0.30 ~ log(2)
 3  0.48 ~ log(3)
 4  0.60 ~ log(4)
-1    .
 5  0.70 ~ log(5)
```

This is just a simplified version of the problem. There are `35000` observations in my dataset and I could not find any simple rules like `drop if v1 <= 0` to solve this problem.

Without screening my data first, one method in my mind is to use `for` loop and run the `log()` function over the observations. However, I couldn't find any websites telling me how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stata will return missing if asked to take the logarithm of zero or negative values. But

```
generate log_x = log(x)
```

and

```
generate log_x = log(x) if x > 0
```

will have precisely the same result, missings in the observations with problematic values.

The bigger question here is statistical. Why do you want to take logarithms of such a variable any way?   If your idea is to transform a variable, then other transformations are available. If the variable is a response or outcome variable, then a generalized linear model with logarithmic link will work even if there are some zero or negative values; the idea is just that the mean function should remain positive.

There have been many, many threads raising these issues on Cross Validated and Statalist.

I can't imagine why you think a loop is either needed or helpful here. With `generate` statements of the kind above, Stata automatically loops over observations.